# How to analyze data in excel efficiently?

Tags: r, excel, analysis

I have a data in excel, columns represent some categories and each row represents individual user's data about the categories.
and they are not sorted in any way. Following is the sample of the data

```
user  food      date      ........
a     pizza     1/1/2013
b     fries     1/3/2013
c     sandwich  5/2/2013
a     sandwich  2/3/2010
```

I want to find probabilities of what kind of food each user has.
so I want output like

```
a  pizza     20%
   sandwich  50%
   fries     30%

b  pizza     10%
   noodle    20%
```

what would be the most efficient way to do this?
I was filtering by users in excel and finding frequencies for each food using R and type all them in excel sheet.

Comment: Using pivot table, I could find the number of types of food a user had but I'm having trouble with finding how many times each food the user had.

Comment: If you want more complicated things, I would simply use a more appropriate tool (R). See my answer for a complete working example.

Comment: You may not like this answer, but:  never EVER use Excel for data analysis.  Aside from things like untraceable formula dependencies and built-in Excel functions having errors, it's just bad sense to use a spreadsheet tool to do math.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know some R, I would recommend you bite the bullet and this kind of work in R altogether. Excel is a tool that has it's uses, but for serious data analysis R is much better, and an investment worth making.

This is how I would do it in R:

```
# Create some sample data
foods = c('pizza', 'sandwich', 'tuna', 'noodles', 'fries')
persons = letters[1:10] # letters is a variable containing all the letters of the alphabet, standarly available in R
df = data.frame(food = sample(foods, 1000, replace = TRUE),
                person = sample(persons, 1000, replace = TRUE))

# Get frequencies
table_df = table(df)
# Divide by total food eaten by each person
# In both `apply` and `sweep`, the `2` refers to performing the operation per column
prob_df = apply(table_df, 2, 
             function(food_per_person) {
                  (food_per_person / sum(food_per_person)) * 100
             })
# An alternative to using `apply` is to use `sweep`:
prob_df = sweep(table_df, 2, margin.table(table_df, 2), FUN = "/")
prob_df
# All close to 20%, as expected
        person
                  a        b        c        d        e        f        g
  fries    21.34831 22.88136 17.17172 19.04762 19.81132 18.34862 16.03774
  noodles  19.10112 19.49153 19.19192 23.80952 18.86792 22.01835 19.81132
  pizza    13.48315 18.64407 16.16162 19.04762 16.03774 13.76147 23.58491
  sandwich 24.71910 21.18644 22.22222 13.09524 23.58491 30.27523 18.86792
  tuna     21.34831 17.79661 25.25253 25.00000 21.69811 15.59633 21.69811
          person
                  h        i        j
  fries    23.14815 18.75000 11.76471
  noodles  17.59259 26.04167 24.70588
  pizza    19.44444 19.79167 18.82353
  sandwich 23.14815 14.58333 24.70588
  tuna     16.66667 20.83333 20.00000
```

And check the outcome, i.e. do the percentages per person add to 100%:

```
colSums(prob_df)
  a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j 
100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can use R little bit but I am still novice in R. So I do not understand how you use food_per_person? Can you explain that part little bit more specifically? Thank you again

Comment: Using `apply` with `MARGIN = 2` you apply a function to each of the columns in `table_df`. This can be a built-in function (e.g. `sum` or `t.test`), or a user defined function. In the `apply` call above I define a function on the fly. The function takes one input argument, `food_per_person` which in this case are the values for one of the columns. Inside the function I divide each column by the sum of the column times 100, i.e. the percentage of the time that the individual values in the column occur.